# Winforms DataGridView cant select right Id and IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

I am trying to get id on click from my datagrid the first 3 work fine but the last one I get an error saying :

**System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'There is no line at position 1003.**

The first 3 elements are from 1-3 the 4th element has it's id as 1003 I don't know why, but shouldn't it work anyway?

Load and Button to select element :

```
    private void EditarComputador_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        opBD.ListaComputadoresPreFeitos("SELECT * FROM ComputadoresPreFeitos");


        dataGridView_PreFeitos.Visible = true;
        List<ComputadoresPrefeitos> lista = new List<ComputadoresPrefeitos>();
        lista = opBD.ListaComputadoresPreFeitos();
        dataGridView_PreFeitos.DataSource = lista;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        id = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView_PreFeitos.Rows[dataGridView_PreFeitos.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value); // Pegar ID

        if (opBD.dtTabelaComputadoresPreFeitos != null && opBD.dtTabelaComputadoresPreFeitos.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataRow linha = opBD.dtTabelaComputadoresPreFeitos.Rows[id];
            textBox1.Text = linha["Id_Prefeitos"].ToString();
            textBox2.Text = linha["Nome"].ToString();
            textBox3.Text = linha["Marca"].ToString();
            textBox4.Text = linha["Preco"].ToString();
        }
        
    }
```

[opBD.dtTabelaComputadoresPreFeitos.Rows[id-1] picks the right elements but still gives me the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy16z.png)

[opBD.dtTabelaComputadoresPreFeitos.Rows[id-1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEr6q.png)

////////////////

[opBD.dtTabelaComputadoresPreFeitos.Rows[id] it picks one element above the other, lets say i click on id 1 it picks id 2 and still gives me the same error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j7ZV.png)

[opBD.dtTabelaComputadoresPreFeitos.Rows[id]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8e7a.png)

Comment: __Do not__ call a `DataGridView`a `GridView` or a `DataGrid` and vice versa!! This is wrong and confusing as those are different controls. Always call things by their __right__ name! - Also : Do not post code as images only!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, your trying to take the Cell's value, `1003` which is your record id, and use it as the row index, which should be `3` for the record in question. This will not work, you should ***never*** rely on the id's matching the row index.

The fix below removes the line that set's the id to the cell value, and uses the `dataGridView_PreFeitos.CurrentRow.Index` property instead.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (opBD.dtTabelaComputadoresPreFeitos != null && opBD.dtTabelaComputadoresPreFeitos.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                // use the dataGridView_PreFeitos.CurrentRow.Index property to get your row
                DataRow linha = opBD.dtTabelaComputadoresPreFeitos.Rows[dataGridView_PreFeitos.CurrentRow.Index];
                textBox1.Text = linha["Id_Prefeitos"].ToString();
                textBox2.Text = linha["Nome"].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = linha["Marca"].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = linha["Preco"].ToString();
            }
        }
```